# Schedule E-mail with @future method

Tags: apex

I have a @future method that works fine with the built in apex scheduler.

I want to schedule this code in apex.

```
public class Chasing {
@future(callout=true)
public static void chaseEmail(){// do something}
```

I try the below.

```
System.schedule('Every 1 min',  '0 1 * * * ? *', new Chasing.chaseEmail());
```

I get the error, not valid type.

Question) How to call this future method in a schedule apex.

Answer (score 2):

You can only schedule a class that implements `Schedulable` interface. Your class doesn't have it.

Check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) for some examples.